# Arriving in the US on a waiver visa but wanting to stay in Canada for one year

Tags: usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program

I have been granted a working visa (IEC) for Canada and it is valid for one year upon entry. I want to travel to San Fran first and travel up the West coast and enter Canada via train. I have been told that I have to have a return ticket from Canada within 90 days because it's a country neighboring the US. Is this true?

Any help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is true for tourists, not Canadian residents. I couldn't find any authoritative statement anywhere on [DHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Homeland_Security) or [CBP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Customs_and_Border_Protection) sites to support this statement.

You must remember though that any stay for less than 30 days in Canada will not reset the 90 days VWP clock.